# "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'test'" using context manager

Tags: python, python-3.x, contextmanager

I have this class:

```py
class Tess:
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.kwargs = kwargs

    def __enter__(self):
        print('fire away!')
        for key, value in self.kwargs.items():
            print(f"{key} and {value}")

    def __exit__(self):
        print('the end.')

    def test(self, **kwargs):        # This takes in a different dict independent of __init__
        # Also tried self.kwargs = kwargs here but doesn't change anything
        for key, value in self.kwargs.items():
            print(f"The end of {key} and {value}")
```

Then I used it within the context-manager.

```py
with Tess(foo='bar') as t:
    t.test(foo_bar='baz')
```

I expected the output to be:

```py
fire away!
foo and bar
The end of foo_bar and baz
the end.
```

It instead gives:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/...", line 145, in <module>
    t.test(foo_bar='baz')
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'test'
```

How do I rectify this? Thanks.

Comment: I got `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'test'` error instead.

Comment: This can be solved by `return self` in `__enter__`. But your error message is weird, where is "css" ?

Comment: @SorousHBakhtiary the actual function was `css()`, I put `test()` here so the name doesn't interfere with anything

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this :

```
class Tess:
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.kwargs = kwargs

    def __enter__(self):
        print('fire away!')
        for key, value in self.kwargs.items():
            print(f"{key} and {value}")
        return self

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        print('the end')

    def test(self, **kwargs):  # This takes in a different dict independent of __init__
        # Also tried self.kwargs = kwargs here but doesn't change anything
        for key, value in self.kwargs.items():
            print(f"The end of {key} and {value}")


with Tess(foo='bar') as t:
    t.test(foo_bar='baz')
```

output :

```
fire away!
foo and bar
The end of foo and bar
the end
```

I made two changes :

1- In order to access `t` in `as t` statement, you should put `return self` in your `__enter__`. `t` is going to be whatever you return from `__enter__`

2- Python passes `exc_type`, `exc_val`, `exc_tb` (type, value, traceback) to `__exit__` method, so you should change your signature to accept those parameters.

Comment: Thanks, `return self` in `__enter__` solved it.